# Hive external table returns no data

Tags: hadoop, hiveql

It's bugging me to the point I am so confused about what I learnt
Here the code I used to create external table in Hive

```
 "CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db.t1"
                    + " (icode String, " +
                    "bill_date String, " +
                    "total_amount float, " +
                    "bill_no String, " +
                    "customer_code String) " +
                    "COMMENT \" Sales details \" " +
                    "ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY \",\" " +
                    "LINES TERMINATED BY \"\n\" " +
                    "STORED AS TEXTFILE " +
                    "LOCATION \"hdfs://saurab:9000/ekbana2/ \" " +
                    "tblproperties(\"skip.header.line.count\"=\"1\")";
```

table is created without any error and `show tables in db` gives me my table `t1`. But when I do `select * from db.t1` it returns blank only the column name. So please clarify 
1) Does `location` refers to the folder when my data is? I mean I have test.csv inside ekbana2 folder in above location or `location` refers to the path where I want my table to be 
2)why is table returning blank?
Here is the file I want to load into external table
[image: location where my file to be loaded is]

Comment: Yes location does represent where the data is

Comment: i don't think you need to provide the full path to hdfs hive is already connected to that directory. try using only /ekbana as location

Comment: How are you executing this snippet?

Comment: Thanks, I had silly typo :(